# Kubernetes doesn't remove completed jobs for a Cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

Kubernetes doesn't delete a manually created completed job when historylimit is set when using newer versions of kubernetes clients.

**mycron.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: myjob
spec:
  schedule: "* * 10 * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1  
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

**Creating cronjob:**

```
kubectl create -f mycron.yaml
```

**Creating job manually:**

```
kubectl create job -n myjob --from=cronjob/hello hello-job
```

**Result:**
Job is completed but not removed

```
NAME            COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
hello-job           1/1           2s     6m
```

Tested with kubernetes server+client versions of 1.19.3 and 1.20.0

However when I used an older client version (1.15.5) against the server's 1.19/1.20 it worked well.

**Comparing the differences while using different client versions:**

**kubernetes-controller log:** 
Using client v1.15.5 I have this line in the log (But  missing when using client v1.19/1.20):

```
 1 event.go:291] "Event occurred" object="myjob/hello" kind="CronJob" apiVersion="batch/v1beta1" type="Normal" reason="SuccessfulDelete" message="Deleted job hello-job"
```

**Job yaml**:
Exactly the same, except the ownerReference part:
*For client v1.19/1.20*

```
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
    kind: CronJob
    name: hello
    uid: bb567067-3bd4-4e5f-9ca2-071010013727
```

*For client v1.15*

```
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: CronJob
    name: hello
    uid: bb567067-3bd4-4e5f-9ca2-071010013727
```

And that is it. No other informations in the logs, no errors, no warnings ..nothing (checked all the pods logs in kube-system)

**Summary:** 
It seems to be a bug in kubectl client itself but not in kubernetes server. But don't know how to proceed further.

**edit:**
When I let the cronjob itself to do the job (ie hitting the time in the expression), it will remove the completed job successfully.

Comment: I ran it and it woks on my cluster (1.20.3). If you provide the output of kubectl version (with build hashes) I can try to replicate it one more time with the exact versions you use. But since you consider it a bug, much better option would be to create an issue on k8s github repo: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues

Comment: @Matt
Created one yesterday : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/100927
Seems it is not a bug, but unsupported intentionally

Comment: Great, It looks like it is a "bug" indeed. My bad for assuming it works. I must have done sth wrong replicating it.